# Clearing dependent dropdown when parent dropdown is changed in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use VBA to clear the product ID cell when the Product cell is changed.  My dropdowns work where Product ID dropdown changes based on what product is selected.  My columns are:
Quantity, Product, Product ID, Description

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I'm completely new to VBA and don't really know what I'm doing.  Any help with this is appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: What is this code doing or not doing which is different from what you expect/want?  If it's not running at all then you may have turned off event handling.  Put `Application.EnableEvents = True` in the Immediate window and hit enter to re-enable events.  Typically when turning off events you want to include some error handling to ensure they get turned back on if there's an error.

Comment: ...for example checking `Target.Validation.Type` will cause a run-time error if Target has no validation applied to it.

Comment: @TimWilliams, if I select a product (call is A) and product ID but realized I should have selected product B instead of product A, I'd like the Product ID cell to clear itself once the product is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub   'screen out multi-cell changes
    If Target.Column <> 2 Then Exit Sub 'col2 only
    If Not CellHasValidation(Target) Then Exit Sub '...with validation
    
    On Error GoTo haveError 'ensure events are not left off
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub

haveError:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

'check if a cell has validation
Function CellHasValidation(cell As Range) As Boolean
    Dim vt
    On Error Resume Next 'ignore if error (no validation)
    vt = cell.Validation.Type
    On Error GoTo 0 'stop ignoring errors
    CellHasValidation = Not IsEmpty(vt)
End Function
```

Comment: Do I need to change anything in the code? I really have no idea what I'm supposed to do with the exception of opening up VBA.

Comment: Right-click on the worksheet Tab >> View Code.  Copy and paste the code from above into the module.  That should do it.

Comment: Nothing happens.  Product ID remains populated even when I change the Product.

Comment: You'll have to do some debugging - worked OK for me in testing.  Is your Product in Col B and ProductId is Col C ?

Comment: Then it should work.  Try the edited version above (added an alert for any error)

Comment: Closed the workbook, opened it up, added the code, and BAM! It works!  Thank you for your patience and help.