# Reset or Clear Adjacent Cells When Previous Cell Changes

Tags: excel, vba, dropdown

I've been scouring the internet for roughly 6 hours trying to find the right vba code, but neither seems to work. I've tried everything from SelectionChange, Change, etc., but can't seem to get it to work.

Here is what I need: I have 3 columns (A, B, & C). They are dropdowns. They are not dependent on named ranges. I used the Data Validation List property.

Data Validation:

1. For column A cells: ='JFG-JF'!$C$1:$ZZ$1
2. For column B cells: =OFFSET(XLOOKUP(A2,'JFG-JF'!$C$1:$K$1,'JFG-JF'!$C$2:$K$16),0,0,ROWS('JFG-JF'!$A:$A)-COUNTIF('JFG-JF'!$C:$C,""),1)
3. For column C cells: =OFFSET(XLOOKUP(B2,'JF-JSF'!$C$1:$AW$1,'JF-JSF'!$C$2:$AW$16),0,0,ROWS('JF-JSF'!$A:$A)-COUNTIF('JF-JSF'!$C:$C,""),1)

All I need is a vba code that ensures any cell change/selection in column A will reset/clear the adjacent cells in column B and C. And if no change in column A, but change in column B, then reset/clear column C cells.

Lastly, I would like part of the code to somehow highlight any selection changed. The color can be orange, yellow - whatever - just need to be able to visually see if a new selection/change was made.

Comment: Already many questions here on this topic - eg see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68547522/clearing-dependent-dropdown-when-parent-dropdown-is-changed-in-excel   More examples: https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+worksheet_change+dependent+dropdown+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: This one works well for what I need - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing the linked forum above, I was able to tweak my coding and it now works perfectly!

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    If Target.Count < 1 Then Exit Sub   
    If Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub 
    If Not CellHasValidation(Target) Then Exit Sub 
    
    On Error GoTo haveError 
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
    Target.Offset(0, 2).Value = ""
    Target.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 44
    Target.Offset(0, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 44
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
```

Comment: This is the second part of the code for the worksheet:

'check if a cell has validation
Function CellHasValidation(cell As Range) As Boolean
    Dim vt
    On Error Resume Next 'ignore if error (no validation)
    vt = cell.Validation.Type
    On Error GoTo 0 'stop ignoring errors
    CellHasValidation = Not IsEmpty(vt)
End Function